# Find object in array of objects where all key-value pairs are unique

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, find

Say I have an array of objects {key:string} where all the keys-value pairs are unique (keys or values are allowed to the same in different objects, but the same key value pair)

```
const arr = [{a_1:"val_1"}, {a_2:"val_2"}, ..., {a_n:"val_n"}];
```

and I have a target object

```
const target = {a_i: "val_i"};
```

I want  to find if `target` exists in `arr` i.e if it's key and value match a certain object in `arr`. If true, then I want the object from `arr` to be returned.

example: (Edited)

```
const target = {foo: "bar"};
const arr = [{foo: "bar"}, {corona: "COVID-19"}, {foo: "notBar"}, {notFoo: "bar"}];
```

In this example, the search of `target` on `arr` will return `{foo:"bar"}` from `arr`.

Note:

```
arr.find(ob => ob === target);
```

returns undefined.

Comment: If you need to simply get `true`/`false` answer, you don't really need `find()`, `some()` suits way better to the purpose, see details in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60829650/11299053) below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there's a single key/value pair in your target option, you may use [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to look up through your source array (until match is found) and extract target key/value, using [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), like that:

```js
const arr = [{a_1:"val_1"}, {a_2:"val_2"}, {a_n:"val_n"}],
      target = {a_2: "val_2"},
      [[targetKey, targetValue]] = Object.entries(target),
      
      hasMatch = arr.some(item => targetKey in item && item[targetKey] == targetValue)
      
console.log(hasMatch)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%;}
```

Comment: Thanks, I guess you can avoid repeating this line `const [key,value] = Object.entries(target)` for each element and place it outside the `some`.

Comment: I've edited my example and assumptions a little, AFTER you answered, your answer is still great. Apologies and thanks

Comment: @GiladGur : if you need matching object, simply replace `some()` with `find()`

Answer (score 2):

Those 2 have different references. Maybe with `JSON.stringify()` it can work.

```js
const target = {foo: "bar"};
const arr = [{foo: "bar"}, {corona: "COVID-19"}];

const result = arr.find(ob => JSON.stringify(ob) === JSON.stringify(target));

console.log(result);
```

Or a better option to use [`.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) as the following:

```js
const target = {foo: "bar"};
const arr = [{foo: "bar"}, {corona: "COVID-19"}];
const keysT = Object.keys(target);

const result = arr.find(e => {
   const keysE = Object.keys(e);
   
   return keysE.length === keysT.length &&
          keysE.every(k => e[k] === target[k])
});

console.log(result);
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: will not work if keys initialized in different order

Comment: @NiklasE.
Do you mean if this is the case?

`const arr = [{corona: "COVID-19"},{foo: "bar"}];`

It will still work.

Comment: If there are more keys then this code is not working

Comment: @MaheerAli Just added a better option to use `.every()`.

Comment: @GiladGur Don't get me wrong. For that this ist absolutely fine! But I wanted to point it out, so if somebody else googles a similar problem with more keys in the object that will not work.

Comment: @NiklasE. What about if we check the length of the keys of each element? Just extended my solution.

Comment: @norbitrial Nice. That is very similar to my answer, you have my upvote.

Comment: I've edited my example and assumptions a little, AFTER you answered, your answer is still great. Apologies and thanks

Answer (score 1):

that will do it if keys are not in order. But not if the key values of the target object objects itself.

```js
const target = {foo: "bar"};
const arr = [{foo: "bar"}, {corona: "COVID-19"}];

arr.find(ob => {
  for (key in target) {
    if (!(key in ob)) return false;
    if (ob[key] !== target[key]) return false;
  }
  return true;
});
```

**Edit:**
With "keys are not in order", I mean:

```
const target = {foo: "bar", bar: "foo"};
const arr = [{bar: "foo", foo: "bar"}, {corona: "COVID-19", foo: "bar"}];
```

Comment: I've edited my example and assumptions a little, AFTER you answered, your answer is still great. Apologies and thanks